# Team and layers programing java+spring+hibernate+flex+jstl

Tags: apache-flex, spring

We have been working on a incremental project for like 4 or 5 years using the technologies mentioned at the end.

The project has been growing, and now i feel our methodology is not effective enough. Until now every programer that has worked on the project has had to learn the entire layer structure and technologies surrounding them, and every new feature is assigned to a single person.

So we are delaying on delivery times, its really hard to train someone and make them productive, and people on the team feel overwhelmed, i don´t think is a matter of money and resources, a debate is on, and i really feel like we should work in pairs and in layers, becoming specialized in certain areas and working in teams. How ever some argument that we can´t work in layers because a person might not be able to finish his part because he won´t be able to test it until the other member is over with his layer. Right now we are only 3 programers.

So if you think that these suggestions make sense, what i need is some nutshell effective references of how can we turn this in a more positive dynamic as a team, how to work on layers with these technologies, i need to have practical solutions and arguments so we can turn the ship to the right direction. Can any one direct us to the right direction ? it will be deeply appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Technologies:

Backend: Java + Spring + Hibernate + Mysql
Frontend HTML: Jstl + html 
Frontend Flex: Flex SDK 3.5 + Blaze DS, cairngorm, third party libraries and sources.
Development OS: Mac or windows
Development Tools: Trac for management, svn repository
Production Environment: Linux Debian or Centos, tomcat 5.5
Tools: Intellij and Flash Builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty open ended question, with no real "right" answer, I think. One thing that can help enable working independently on different layers is to first design a contract/interface between the layers. Then you can work on both layers independently, on one side working to fulfill the contract/interface, and on the other side working to build on the data/functionality provided by the contract. You can start out with some kind of mock implementations of the contract/interface on one side, and a mock consumer of the data/functionality on the other side. This can work within your Java/Spring/Hibernate/MySQL backend as well as across the backend and frontend. You're still going to have times where you need to actually integrate your layers and test that integration, which will create dependencies between the completion of work in different layers.

Comment: +1 for suggesting interfaces. This is actually quite critical. In addition, architectural frameworks can help with this task as well - in a large application I designed last year we implemented robotlegs and with the .net and oracle dba's we were able to hash out most of the methods and it's parameters. With that in tow, the front-end team was able to work with a self-injecting test model / objects to hammer out the ui in parallel to middle-ware development.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. contract/interface... we got interfaces for every method with spring, but im not sure how to use them really for the issue at hand. And contract is a concept im not familiar with, but what i infer is that we should write a document where we speicifed the imput and outputs of every methods ? but how does interfaces fit on this ?.  i belive the frameworks we are using (spring/cairngorm) deliver the benefits needed, since it decouples the layers and both are MVC frameworks. Thank you very much for your time